# How do I compile Typescript to with nodejs 4?

Tags: node.js, typescript

now that nodejs4 support classes and arrow functions, how do I tell typescript not to polyfill it?

Comment: target es6 isn't reliable for a node target yet. See my answer for an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> now that nodejs4 support classes and arrow functions, how do I tell typescript not to polyfill it

You might think you can use `target es6`, *but don't*. E.g. the following in TypeScript :

```
function test(bar = 123){

}
```

Compiles to JavaScript with target es6:

```
function test(bar = 123) {
}
```

**But default parameters aren't supported by node yet** ([reference](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/))

Till the compatibility table of Node *exceeds* that of *TypeScript* ... be very careful! or just `target es5`.

Comment: That's what I thought.... I think that babel can disable specific es6 features...

Comment: Yes ... because its emitter is *transformer* (plugin) based ... so specific transformations can be switched on or off. TypeScript is a bit more monolithic (but in turn easier to read IMHO)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using TypeScript now for node, you are likely specifying that your target output is ES5. Which means that it will polyfill/transpile ES6/7 features into the paradigm of ES5 in order to run in today's browsers and previous versions of node.

In order to use those features of ES6 today in node v4 you would just need to change your build process to output ES6 via the target option.

Note: this is true if you are using command line arguments or a tsconfig.json